# Bash builtins also available as separate executables

Tags: bash, fork, exec, built-in

I wanted to understand bash builtins. Hence the following questions:

1. When I think of the term *builtin* I am thinking that the `bash` executable has a function defined in its symbol table that other parts of the executable can access *without actually having to `fork`*. Is this what *builtin* means?
2. I also see that some builtins have a separate executable. For instance `type [` returns `[ is a shell builtin`. But then I also see an executable named `/usr/bin/[`. Is it correct to say that the same code is available through two executables: one through `bash` program and another through `/usr/bin/[`?

Comment: Unix.SE: [What is the difference between a builtin command and one that is not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/what-is-the-difference-between-a-builtin-command-and-one-that-is-not)

Comment: Unix.SE: [Why is echo a shell built in command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/why-is-echo-a-shell-built-in-command)

Comment: Unix.SE: [Understanding shell builtin commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442945/understanding-shell-builtin-commands)

Comment: Indirectly related: Unix.SE: [Why does POSIX require certain shell built-ins to have an external implementation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496341/why-does-posix-require-certain-shell-built-ins-to-have-an-external-implementatio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, the program version of the built-ins is used when the shell interpreter is not available or not needed. Let's explain it in more details...

When you run a shell script, the interpreter recognizes the built-ins and will not *fork/exec* but merely call the function corresponding to the built-in. Even if you call them from an C/C++ executable through `system()`, the latter launches a shell first and then makes the spawn shell run the built-in.
Here is an example program, which runs `echo message` thanks to `system()` library service:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  system("echo message");

  return 0;
}
```

Compile it and run it:

```
$ gcc msg.c -o msg
$ ./msg
message
```

Running the latter under `strace` with the `-f` option shows the involved processes. The main program is executed:

```
$ strace -f ./msg
execve("./msg", ["./msg"], 0x7ffef5c99838 /* 58 vars */) = 0
```

Then, `system()` triggers a `fork()` which is actually a `clone()` system call. The child process#5185 is launched:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f7e6d6cbff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_VFORK|SIGCHLD
strace: Process 5185 attached
 <unfinished ...>
```

The child process executes `/bin/sh -c "echo message"`. The latter shell calls the `echo` built-in to display the message on the screen (`write()` system call):

```
[pid  5185] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "echo message"], 0x7ffdd0fafe28 /* 58 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[...]
[pid  5185] write(1, "message\n", 8message
)    = 8
[...]
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The program version of the built-ins is useful when you need them from a C/C++ executable without an intermediate shell for the sake of the performances. For instance, when you call them through `execv()` function.
Here is an example program which does the same thing as the preceding example but with `execv()` instead of `system()`:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *av[3];

  av[0] = "/bin/echo";
  av[1] = "message";
  av[2] = NULL;
  execv(av[0], av);

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it to see that we get the same result:

```
$ gcc msg1.c -o msg1
$ ./msg1
message
```

Let's run it under `strace` to get the details. The output is shorter because no sub-process is involved to execute an intermediate shell. The actual `/bin/echo` program is executed instead:

```
$ strace -f ./msg1
execve("./msg1", ["./msg1"], 0x7fffd5b22ec8 /* 58 vars */) = 0
[...]
execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "message"], 0x7fff6562fbf8 /* 58 vars */) = 0
[...]
write(1, "message \1\n", 10message 
)            = 10
[...]
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Of course, if the program is supposed to do additional things, a simple call to `execv()` is not sufficient as it overwrites itself by the `/bin/echo` program. A more elaborated program would fork and execute the latter program but without the need to run an intermediate shell:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
  if (fork() == 0) {

    char *av[3];

    av[0] = "/bin/echo";
    av[1] = "message";
    av[2] = NULL;
    execv(av[0], av);
  }

  wait(NULL);

  // Make additional things before ending

  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run it under `strace` to see that the intermediate child process executes the `/bin/echo` program without the need of an intermediate shell:

```
$ gcc msg2.c -o msg2
$ ./msg2
message
$ strace -f ./msg2
execve("./msg2", ["./msg2"], 0x7ffc11a5e228 /* 58 vars */) = 0
[...]
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLDstrace: Process 5703 attached
, child_tidptr=0x7f8e0b6e0810) = 5703
[pid  5703] execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "message"], 0x7ffe656a9d08 /* 58 vars */ <unfinished ...>
[...]
[pid  5703] write(1, "message\n", 8message
)    = 8
[...]
[pid  5703] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed>NULL, 0, NULL)       = 5703
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=5703, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Thanks so very much @Rachid k. That clarifies everything for me!

Answer (score 3):

> the bash executable has a function defined in its symbol table

There are builtins that are included inside Bash executable. You can load builtins dynamically from a separate shared library on runtime.

> can access without actually having to fork

Yes.

> Is it correct to say that the same code is available through two executables: one through bash executable and another through /usr/bin/[?

No, it's a different source code. One is a Bash builtin and the other is a program. It will be a different source code. There is also different behavior in grey areas.

```
$ printf "%q\n" '*'
\*
$ /bin/printf "%q\n" '*'
'*'

$ time echo 1
1

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$ /bin/time echo 1
1
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 50%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2392maxresident)k
64inputs+0outputs (1major+134minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ [ -v a ]
$ /bin/[ -v a ]
/bin/[: ‘-v’: unary operator expected
```